# Calculating expired vouchers, given a fixed window

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

**Problem:**

I have time series data for vouchers being earned and redeemed. Vouchers only last for a **3 day fixed window** including the day they were earnt eg. a voucher earnt on 1st Jan would be active for 1st, 2nd & 3rd.

I need to make an assumption that it's first come first served when it comes to redemptions happening against them being earned. E.g. if we have the data

```
Date       VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed
01/01/2020             10                0
02/01/2020              8                9
03/01/2020              4                4
04/01/2020              2                4
05/01/2020              1                4
```

then on 2nd, those 9 vouchers are from the 1st ie we have remaining vouchers

```
Date       VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed RemainingVouchers
01/01/2020             10                0                 1
02/01/2020              8                9                 8
```

then on the 3rd, those 4 redemptions will be the remaining 1 from the 1st and 3 from the 2nd

```
Date       VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed RemainingVouchers
01/01/2020             10                0                 0
02/01/2020              8                9                 5
03/01/2020              4                4                 0
```

the 4th:

```
Date       VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed RemainingVouchers
01/01/2020             10                0                 0
02/01/2020              8                9                 1
03/01/2020              4                4                 4
04/01/2020              2                4                 2
```

the 5th:

```
Date       VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed RemainingVouchers
01/01/2020             10                0                 0
02/01/2020              8                9                 1**
03/01/2020              4                4                 0
04/01/2020              2                4                 2
05/01/2020              1                4                 1
```

So on the 5th we have our first expired voucher as the ** one wasn't used up in it's 3 day period.

I need to calculate at any point in time how many vouchers there are that expire using this logic flow. I can figure out how to do it in my head, going through line by line like above. But I'm struggling to see how to do it in a vectorised way, that could also work in MSSQL. If it was just in R I could brute force it with a loop. I have also posted this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504743/calculating-expired-vouchers-given-a-fixed-window) but had no feedback yet so extending this to the programming community.

**Data:**

I have included an `R dput` at the end but here is what it looks like
**Edit:** There is some new data at the end of this summary that's a more tricky example

```
        Date VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed ActualActive ActualExpired CumulativeEarned
1 01/01/2020             10                0           10             0               10
2 02/01/2020              8                9            9             0               18
3 03/01/2020              4                4            9             0               22
4 04/01/2020              2                4            7             0               24
5 05/01/2020              1                4            3             1               25
6 06/01/2020              0                1            2             0               25
7 07/01/2020              0                1            0             1               25
8 08/01/2020              0                0            0             0               25
  CumulativeRedeemed CumulativeDiff
1                  0             10
2                  9              9
3                 13              9
4                 17              7
5                 21              4
6                 22              3
7                 23              2
8                 23              2
```

`ActualActive` & `ActualExpired` are the numbers I get to with pen and paper. Note that I put them on the date they expired, rather than against the date they were earned. Either would work for me, just changes the reporting view. I can get the total vouchers in play by looking at the `CumulativeEarned` & `CumulativeRedeemed` and then taking the difference. I think then if I can just get the Expired ones, then calculating the active is simple.

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it as I seem to have a mental block on this today! Thank you! :)

**Edit:** My actual problem is a 28 day window, this is a simplified view :)

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2020", "02/01/2020", "03/01/2020", 
"04/01/2020", "05/01/2020", "06/01/2020", "07/01/2020", "08/01/2020"
), VouchersEarned = c(10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VouchersRedeemed = c(0L, 
9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ActualActive = c(10L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 0L), ActualExpired = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), CumulativeEarned = c(10L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L), CumulativeRedeemed = c(0L, 9L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
23L), CumulativeDiff = c(10L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

**Edit 2:** **My latest attempt in R**. Something is off though, but I feel like it's not impossible with the right combination of lagged columns

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, Date := lubridate::dmy(Date)]  

# functional form
findExpiredVouchers <- function(dt, period=3){
  
  #  generation of cumulative data
  dt[, CumulativeEarned := cumsum(VouchersEarned)]
  dt[, CumulativeRedeemed := cumsum(VouchersRedeemed)]
  dt[, CumulativeDiff := CumulativeEarned-CumulativeRedeemed]
  
  # I think if we look at the cumulative earned against the cumulative redeemed,
  # plus it's lag period from that point, ie the cumulative redeemed in 2 days,
  # then we can see for data prior to last 3 which have expired
  dt[, LaggedCumulativeRedeemed := shift(CumulativeRedeemed, period-1, type="lead")]
  dt[, ExpiredCumulative := CumulativeEarned - LaggedCumulativeRedeemed]
  
  # Now this creates negative values though for eg the first case, I'm not 100%
  # if I need to worry about these
  dt[ExpiredCumulative < 0, ExpiredCumulative := 0]
  
  # so now it should be the difference in this series that captures the origin
  # of an expiration
  dt[, Expired := c(NA, diff(ExpiredCumulative))]
  dt[1, Expired := ExpiredCumulative]
  
  # and I can shift this by the lag period to get the end result
  dt[, OutputExpired := shift(Expired, period, type="lag")]
  dt[is.na(OutputExpired), OutputExpired := 0]
  
  # and active
  dt[, CumulativeExpired := cumsum(OutputExpired)]
  dt[, OutputActive := CumulativeDiff-CumulativeExpired]
}
dt <- findExpiredVouchers(dt, 3)
dt[] # OutputExpired & OutputActive
```

With some new fake data, flaws are exposed as negative expirations come out :(

```
set.seed(1)
p = 0.2
new_dt <- data.table(
  Date = 1:10,
  VouchersEarned = sample(0:15, 10, replace=TRUE)
  )
new_dt[, CumulativeEarned := cumsum(VouchersEarned)]

# fake VouchersRedeemed
new_dt[, VouchersRedeemed := as.integer(NA)]
new_dt[, CumulativeDiff := CumulativeEarned]
for(i in 1:nrow(new_dt)){
  new_value <- sum(rbinom(new_dt$CumulativeDiff[i], 1, p))
  new_dt[i, VouchersRedeemed := new_value]
  new_dt[i:.N, CumulativeDiff := CumulativeDiff - new_value]
}

new_dt <- findExpiredVouchers(dt=new_dt, 3)
new_dt[] # OutputExpired < 0
```

new example

```
    Date VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed OutputExpired
 1:    1              8                1             0
 2:    2              3                1             0
 3:    3              6                3             0
 4:    4              0                1             3
 5:    5              1                1             2
 6:    6             12                5             5
 7:    7              6                5            -5
 8:    8             10                3            -4
 9:    9             13                7             9
10:   10              1                8            -1
```

Running **Waldi's** loop shows a similar result but the -5, -4 and 9 cancel to be 0's (as they should!)

Comment: My actual data is in SQL and that's ideally where a solution would lie. It's a secure private database, I can't share access to that. For now I'm stuck with how I can actually do this with data using techniques common to R and SQL eg long/wide data transformations, column lags and data joins. SQL isn't great with loops so I'm trying to figure out if a solution is even possible.

Comment: . . Whether or not this is possible in SQL depends on the capabilities of the database.  There is no "generic" SQL solution (or more specifically, there might be a Standard SQL solution but few databases would support that syntax).

Comment: Ah ok it says MSSQL but I've added sql-server tag too. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: . . Yes, that identifies the database.

Comment: Logical question: on Jan 1, there are `10` vouchers earned and `0` redeemed`. Why are there not `10` vouchers remaining? My presumption about rows in a longitudinal (daily) table is that the data on a row is either completely self-contained, or relevant using data up to *but not beyond* its date. (I apologize if I'm misunderstanding the meaning of those fields.)

Comment: No worries! A voucher is valid for 3 days. On the 1st it's true that there are 10 vouchers remaining. But on the 2nd there are 9 redemptions, and so only 1/10 of those vouchers is remaining. But I get that changing past data is good to avoid. In the output data I've put the expired voucher from the eg not against the 2nd (where 1 of those 8 expired), but on the day of expiry, the 5th, so that it is observational and looking back. The `VouchersRemaining` was just as an aide to show how I pair up the vouchers earned and redeemed to calculate expired by hand, as data comes in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the tidyverse libraries, in particular [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/), and [magrittr](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/), you can write this code

```
df %<>%  
  mutate(VouchersEarnedCumsum = cumsum(VouchersEarned),
         VouchersRedeemedCumsum = cumsum(VouchersRedeemed),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = VouchersEarnedCumsum - lead(VouchersRedeemedCumsum, 2, default = max(VouchersRedeemedCumsum)),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = as.numeric(VouchersCumsumDifference),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = case_when(VouchersCumsumDifference < 0 ~ 0, T ~ VouchersCumsumDifference),
         ExpiredVouchers = VouchersCumsumDifference - lag(VouchersCumsumDifference, default = 0),
         ExpiredVouchersInDate = lag(ExpiredVouchers, 3, default = 0))
```

The resulting table, starting from your dataframe df, is

```
    # A tibble: 8 x 8
      Date       VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed VouchersEarnedCumsum VouchersRedeemedCumsum VouchersCumsumDifference ExpiredVouchers ExpiredVouchersInDate
      <chr>               <int>            <int>                <int>                  <int>                    <dbl>           <dbl>                 <dbl>
    1 01/01/2020             10                0                   10                      0                        0               0                     0
    2 02/01/2020              8                9                   18                      9                        1               1                     0
    3 03/01/2020              4                4                   22                     13                        1               0                     0
    4 04/01/2020              2                4                   24                     17                        2               1                     0
    5 05/01/2020              1                4                   25                     21                        2               0                     1
    6 06/01/2020              0                1                   25                     22                        2               0                     0
    7 07/01/2020              0                1                   25                     23                        2               0                     1
    8 08/01/2020              0                0                   25                     23                        2               0                     0
```

Then, it is quite easy to translate each function in corresponding SQL queries using dbplyr, with [translate_sql](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/translate_sql.html).

I'm not sure this code works in every situation you're going to face, I recommend to test it extensively.

**EDIT**
I think this corrected code solves the problem.

```
df %<>%  
  mutate(VouchersEarnedCumsum = cumsum(VouchersEarned),
         VouchersRedeemedCumsum = cumsum(VouchersRedeemed),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = VouchersEarnedCumsum - lead(VouchersRedeemedCumsum, 2, default = max(VouchersRedeemedCumsum)),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = as.numeric(VouchersCumsumDifference),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = case_when(VouchersCumsumDifference < 0 ~ 0, T ~ VouchersCumsumDifference),
         VouchersCumsumDifference = accumulate(VouchersCumsumDifference, max),
         ExpiredVouchers = VouchersCumsumDifference - lag(VouchersCumsumDifference, default = 0),
         ExpiredVouchersInDate = lag(ExpiredVouchers, 3, default = 0))
```

Comment: Hey Edoch, thanks for your help. I believe is the same methodology as the solution in my Edit 2 I posted yesterday. There is a `new_dt` in there that doesn't work with both solutions unfortunately :(

Comment: Hi, take a look at the edited code, it seems to work now even with new_dt. I also tried with another seed, and it looks ok.

Comment: Thank you for this, Edoch. It looks promising :). I'll test it out some more and talk to my co-worker about whether the `purrr::accumulate` can be done in SQL

Comment: I think that it can be translated in SQL with something like SELECT MAX(VouchersCumsumDifference) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS VouchersCumsumDifferenceCorrected

Comment: Oo thank you! Better than the bit I had: `select A.[Date], max(B.Value) from @vouchers A
inner join @vouchers B on A.[Date] >= B.[Date]
group by A.[Date]`

Comment: I've got a working version in SQL now using this logic. I'll post it as an answer for completion. Thanks for your help on this! :)

Comment: No problem ;) Bye!

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the total vouchers expired at a point in time you can use the following query and get the value from the max date line. If not exactly what you need, perhaps it can be a good starting point.

```
declare @vouchers table (VDate date, VouchersEarned int, VouchersRedeemed int);
insert  @vouchers values
('2020-01-01', 10, 0),
('2020-01-02', 8, 9),
('2020-01-03', 4, 4),
('2020-01-04', 2, 4),
('2020-01-05', 1, 4),
('2020-01-06', 0, 1),
('2020-01-07', 0, 1),
('2020-01-08', 0, 0);

--select * from @vouchers;

declare @expiry_days int = 3;
declare @start_date date = '2020-01-01';
declare @end_date date = '2020-01-08';

with tally_cte (N) as ( --just a list of numbers 1-n
        --need at lease as many rows as dates in date range other options including a permanent tally table here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql
        -- 1000 rows
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
), days_cte as (    --a list of all dates in date range to include records for days with no earned or redeemed
        select VDate = dateadd(day, t.N - 1, @start_date)
        from tally_cte t
        where t.N <= datediff(day, @start_date, @end_date) + 1
)
select  xed.VDate, xed.VouchersEarned, xed.VouchersRedeemed, xed.CumulativeEarned, xed.CumulativeRedeemed
                , Expiring = lag(xed.Expiring, 1, 0) over (order by xed.VDate)
from    (--determine expired vouchers with a lag
        select  xing.VDate, xing.VouchersEarned, xing.VouchersRedeemed, xing.CumulativeEarned, xing.CumulativeRedeemed
                , Expiring = case when xing.Expiring < 0 then 0 else xing.Expiring end
        from    (--determine expiring vouchers
                select  v.*
                        , Expiring = lag(v.CumulativeEarned, @expiry_days - 1, 0) over (order by v.VDate) - v.CumulativeRedeemed
                from    (--basic query with cumulative earned and redeemed
                        select  v.*
                                , CumulativeEarned = sum(v.VouchersEarned) over (order by v.VDate)
                                , CumulativeRedeemed = sum(v.VouchersRedeemed) over (order by v.vDate)
                        from    days_cte d
                        join    @vouchers v
                                on  v.VDate = d.VDate
                        ) v
                ) xing
        ) xed
order   by xed.VDate;
```

Output:

```
VDate      VouchersEarned VouchersRedeemed CumulativeEarned CumulativeRedeemed Expiring
---------- -------------- ---------------- ---------------- ------------------ -----------
2020-01-01 10             0                10               0                  0
2020-01-02 8              9                18               9                  0
2020-01-03 4              4                22               13                 0
2020-01-04 2              4                24               17                 0
2020-01-05 1              4                25               21                 1
2020-01-06 0              1                25               22                 1
2020-01-07 0              1                25               23                 2
2020-01-08 0              0                25               23                 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the SQL, I'll have a run through, see how it's working. I posted some new data in R language that outlined flaws in the approaches seen so far. It's at the bottom of the summary, but the SQL insert would be ('2020-01-01', 8,  1),
('2020-01-02', 3,  1),
('2020-01-03', 6,  3),
('2020-01-04', 0,  1),
('2020-01-05', 1,  1),
('2020-01-06', 12, 5),
('2020-01-07', 6,  5),
('2020-01-08', 10, 3),
('2020-01-09', 13, 7),
('2020-01-10', 1,  8);

Answer (score 2):

Didn't find a vectorized solution either, so back to loops with a queue to handle vouchers expiration period:

```
# Create new columns
df$calcExpired <- rep(0,nrow(df))
df$calcActive <- rep(0,nrow(df))

# Voucher validity
validity <- 3

# Create an empty queue
qEarned <- rep(0,validity)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  # Expired vouchers
  if (qEarned[1]>0) {
    Expired <-qEarned[1] 
  } else { 
    Expired <- 0
  }
  
  # New values
  Earned <- df$VouchersEarned[i]
  Redeemed <- df$VouchersRedeemed[i]
  
  # Push new value in queue
  qEarned <- c(qEarned[2:validity],Earned)
  
  # Empty the queue
  for (j in 1:validity) {
    if (Redeemed == 0) {
      break
    } 
    else {
      if (Redeemed <= qEarned[j]) {
        qEarned[j] <- qEarned[j] - Redeemed;
        Redeemed <- 0
        break;
      } else {
        Redeemed <- Redeemed - qEarned[j]
        qEarned[j] <- 0
      }
    }
  }

  # Store / output results
  Active <- sum(qEarned)
  df$calcActive[i] <- Active
  df$calcExpired[i] <- Expired
  cat('queue:',qEarned,' - Active:',Active,' - Expired:',Expired,'\n')
}

queue: 0 0 10  - Active: 10  - Expired: 0 
queue: 0 1 8  - Active: 9  - Expired: 0 
queue: 0 5 4  - Active: 9  - Expired: 0 
queue: 1 4 2  - Active: 7  - Expired: 0 
queue: 0 2 1  - Active: 3  - Expired: 1 
queue: 1 1 0  - Active: 2  - Expired: 0 
queue: 0 0 0  - Active: 0  - Expired: 1 
queue: 0 0 0  - Active: 0  - Expired: 0
```

In T-SQL, you'll probably need a stored procedure returning a table to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it's useful for me to see if written out like this as I didn't have time until today to look back at this. I've been tinkering and I can get close using `shift` and differences, so I feel there must be a way. This solution is a big help in verifying my vectorised attempts, but I haven't given up hope yet! :)

Answer (score 2):

For interest I am adding another option that works with both data sets (even though you have already solved it!). Note that this is pretty fixed on a 3 day expiry...if the expiry is larger then you need an extra column and an extra set of case statements that follow the same pattern. This one uses a recursive CTE. Perhaps it will be useful to someone else :-)

```
declare @vouchers table (VDate date, VouchersEarned int, VouchersRedeemed int);
insert  @vouchers values
--('2020-01-01', 10, 0),
--('2020-01-02', 8, 9),
--('2020-01-03', 4, 4),
--('2020-01-04', 2, 4),
--('2020-01-05', 1, 4),
--('2020-01-06', 0, 1),
--('2020-01-07', 0, 1),
--('2020-01-08', 0, 0);
('2020-01-01', 8, 1),
('2020-01-02', 3, 1),
('2020-01-03', 6, 3),
('2020-01-04', 0, 1),
('2020-01-05', 1, 1),
('2020-01-06', 12, 5),
('2020-01-07', 6, 5),
('2020-01-08', 10, 3),
('2020-01-09', 13, 7),
('2020-01-10', 1, 8);

--select * from @vouchers;

with cte as (
        --anchor element - day 1 data
        select  v.VDate, v.VouchersEarned, v.VouchersRedeemed, RemToday = v.VouchersEarned - v.VouchersRedeemed, Rem2Day = 0, Rem3Day = 0, ExpiredToday = 0
        from    @vouchers v
        where   v.VDate = (select min(VDate) from @vouchers)

        union all

        --recursive element - based on previous day totals
        select  v.vdate, v.VouchersEarned, v.VouchersRedeemed
                , RemToday = case   when v.VouchersEarned + c.RemToday + c.Rem2Day < v.VouchersRedeemed then 0  --overflow shouldn't happen - can't redeem more than exist
                                    when c.RemToday + c.Rem2Day < v.VouchersRedeemed            --partial use
                                        then v.VouchersEarned + c.RemToday + c.Rem2Day - v.VouchersRedeemed 
                                    else v.VouchersEarned end                                   --not used
                , Rem2Day = case    when c.RemToday + c.Rem2Day < v.VouchersRedeemed then 0     --overflow use
                                    when c.Rem2Day < v.VouchersRedeemed                         --partial use
                                        then c.RemToday + c.Rem2Day - v.VouchersRedeemed 
                                    else c.RemToday end                                         --not used
                                    --when c.Rem2Day > v.VouchersRedeemed then c.RemToday       --not used
                                    --else c.RemToday + c.Rem2Day - v.VouchersRedeemed end      --partial use
                , Rem3Dat = case    when c.Rem2Day < v.VouchersRedeemed then 0                  --overflow use
                                    else c.Rem2Day - v.VouchersRedeemed end                     --partial use
                , Expired = c.Rem3Day
        from    cte c
        join    @vouchers v
                on  v.VDate = dateadd(day, 1, c.VDate)
)
select  *
from    cte c
order   by c.VDate;
```

Comment: Ah this is cool! It's the manual method I do in pen and paper/excel to validate the solutions. Annoyingly the period I have is 28 days so I'll stick with what I have for now but I appreciate the effort! What I have noticed in testing is if there are more redemptions than are possible ie bad data, it does break Edoch's answer. But I can't see a good way around it. I'm hoping I don't need a way around it as it shouldn't be possible... but real data is usually broken ha

Answer (score 1):

For those interested I have at least a working version of Edoch's R code in SQL:
I've added a grouping variable `StoreId` here to mimic closer my actual data, but the logic doesn't change.

```
declare @vouchers table (Date date, StoreId int, VouchersEarned int, VouchersRedeemed int);
insert  @vouchers values
('2020-01-01', 1, 8, 1), ('2020-01-02', 1, 3, 1), ('2020-01-03', 1, 6, 3), ('2020-01-04', 1, 0, 1), ('2020-01-05', 1, 1, 1), ('2020-01-06', 1, 12, 5), ('2020-01-07', 1, 6, 5), ('2020-01-08', 1, 10, 3), ('2020-01-09', 1, 13, 7), ('2020-01-10', 1, 1, 8),
('2020-01-01', 2, 7, 2), ('2020-01-02', 2, 4, 0), ('2020-01-03', 2, 3, 1), ('2020-01-04', 2, 1, 1), ('2020-01-05', 2, 3, 1), ('2020-01-06', 2, 10, 5), ('2020-01-07', 2, 6, 4), ('2020-01-08', 2, 8, 2), ('2020-01-09', 2, 11, 6), ('2020-01-10', 2, 3, 7);

declare @expiry_days int = 3;

-- add the cumulatives in to the raw data
With base as (
    Select 
    *
    ,SUM(VouchersEarned) OVER(PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY Date ROWS  BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS VouchersEarnedCumsum
    ,SUM(VouchersRedeemed) OVER(PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY Date ROWS  BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS VouchersRedeemedCumsum
    from @vouchers
),
-- pull the redemption point back to the time of earning the vouchers, the lead
base_lead as (
    select 
    * 
    ,VouchersEarnedCumsum - lead(VouchersRedeemedCumsum, @expiry_days-1) over (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY Date) as VouchersCumsumDifference
    from base
),
-- handle the negative values
base_lead_nonzero as (
    select 
    *
    ,Case when VouchersCumsumDifference < 0 then 0 else VouchersCumsumDifference end as VouchersCumsumDifference2
    from base_lead
),
-- now handle the periods where negatives and positives balance out and should be 0, by doing accumulate 
    base_lead_corrected as (
    select 
    *
    ,MAX(VouchersCumsumDifference2) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS VouchersCumsumDifference3
    from base_lead_nonzero
-- take the difference to isolate the expirations
), final_view as (
    select
    *
    ,VouchersCumsumDifference3 - lag(VouchersCumsumDifference3, 1, 0) over (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY Date) as ExpiredVouchers
    from base_lead_corrected
)
select 
*,
lag(ExpiredVouchers, @expiry_days, 0) over (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY Date) as ExpiredVouchersInDate
from final_view
```

Thanks also to Waldi & SMM for respectively providing me with a reliable method for testing the new answers and a framework for the SQL code :)

Comment: I tried something similar yesterday but got pulled away before I could debug my issues :-). When I looked at it again I decided to try what I posted as a 2nd answer. Interesting brain twister!